# Check the radio button value and append the divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on rating feedback form, I have been trying to get my radio button values, based on the value if it is    `<= 3`, have to append question 1, else ( `<= 5`  ) have to append question 2.

I have been trying to get value and append function , I am unable to I do not know where I am missing below is my html and jquery code.

Edit : Thanks Rino Raj got an idea now working fine.

Edit : Thanks Acharki Star inverse was my mistake and I have sorted duplication of div using remove ()
Edit : I accept your answer Mr.Rino raj

**[Fiddle HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/manjula_dhamodharan/smof8b52/)**

**HTML**

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <h2>Rate the videos</h2>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
</fieldset>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.rating input[name="rating"]').on('click', function () {

        var n = $('.rating input[name="rating"]:checked').val();
        alert('hi');


        if (n <= 3) {
            $('fieldset').append("<div>Question1</div>");
        }
        if (n <= 5) {
            $('fieldset').append("<div>Question2</div>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you want the rating value inside the div?

Comment: Start by enabling jquery for your fiddle

Comment: Please let me know if you need any change in my answer. If my answer is correct you can accept it or if you need any change you can add a comment below my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/smof8b52/3/)**

```
$('.rating input[name="rating"]').on('click', function() {
  var n = $('.rating input[name="rating"]:checked').val();
  alert(n);
  if (n <= 3) {
    $('fieldset').append("<div class='newbox'>Question1</div>");
  } else {
    $('fieldset').append("<div class='newbox'>Question2</div>");
  }
});
```

**Changes made**

► Corrected the values in the HTML input

► Chaged to `if` and `else` in the click function

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smof8b52/10/)**

Not sure why your stars are inversed? you should add `else` statement in your code in it will works :

```
$('.rating input[name="rating"]').on('click', function() {
  var n = $(this).val();        

  $newBox = $('.newbox');
  if (n <= 3) {
    $newBox.html("<div class='newbox'>Question1</div>");
  }else if(n <= 5) {
    $newBox.html("<div class='newbox'>Question2</div>");
  }
});
```

**NOTE :** To avoid div duplication you could fix it in your HTML code then just append the text to it according to the selected rate.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('.rating input[name="rating"]').on('click', function() {
  var n = $('.rating input[name="rating"]:checked').val();        

  if (n <= 3) {
    $('.newbox').html("Question1</div>");
  }else{
    $('.newbox').html("<div class='newbox'>Question2</div>");
  }
});
```

```css
    fieldset {outline:none;border:none; }
    .rating {
     float:left;
}

/* :not(:checked) is a filter, so that browsers that don’t support :checked don’t 
   follow these rules. Every browser that supports :checked also supports :not(), so
   it doesn’t make the test unnecessarily selective */
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:200%;
    line-height:1.2;
    color:#ddd;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #bbb, 2px 2px #666, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}

.rating > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #f70;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #c60, 2px 2px #940, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: gold;
    text-shadow:1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating > input:checked + label:hover,
.rating > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #ea0;
    text-shadow:1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating > label:active {
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
    left:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="rating">
  <h2>Rate the videos</h2>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
  <br>
  <div class='newbox'></div>
</fieldset>
```